# How to make a command case insensitive in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How would one make a command case-insensitive without adding many aliases for different capitalizations like this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True, name = 'test', aliases=['Test', 'tEst', 'teSt', 'tesT', 'TEst', 'TeSt', 'TesT', 'tESt', 'tEsT'])
async def test(self, ctx):
    #do stuff
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On the rewrite branch, `commands.Bot` accepts a [`case_insensitive`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.case_insensitive) parameter

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)
```

Note that there is a performance loss when using this feature.

Comment: do you need to import any other module for this to work cause it ain't working?

Comment: how much of a performance lose?

Answer (score 4):

I am not personally familiar with **discord.py**, and may be wrong about this.

It looks to me like case-insensitivity is not a feature of **discord.py** and will not become one in the future, [according to this Github thread](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/466).  And I quote:

> I won't add this natively. However in the rewrite supporting this is simple from the user end:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
  ctx = await self.get_context(message)
  if ctx.prefix is not None:
    ctx.command = self.commands.get(ctx.invoked_with.lower())
    await self.invoke(ctx)
```

So it looks to me like you can just provide your own `on_message` as above, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I found a weird way of doing this when making my first discord bot not knowing of the "case_insensitive" property.
I instead used this in my "on_message" function.

```
await bot.process_commands(msg.content.lower())
```

You can use `commands.process_commands()` instead since you are in a Cog.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use
`if message.content.lower().startswith('command'):`
doesnt necessarily have to be startswith