# Discord.py How do i make it so this doesn't convert urls and arguments to lower case and only make it convert commands?

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I make this only convert commands and not arguments or urls?

because if i do `>play UrL` it converts the url to lower case `>play url`. I want it only to convert the command and not the url/arguments e.g. `>say Hi`: I don't want that to convert to `>say hi`, I want to only convert the command: `>SaY Hi` to `>say Hi`.

code:

```
message.content = message.content.lower().replace(' ', '')
await client.process_commands(message)
```

the whole code

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
    if message.author.nick is None:
        author = message.author.display_name
        content = message.content
        channel = message.channel
        print('{}: {}'.format(author, content))
        print('Channel: {}'.format(channel))
        print(' ')
        message.content = message.content.lower().replace(' ', ' ')
        await client.process_commands(message)
    else:
        author = message.author.nick
        content = message.content
        channel = message.channel
        print('{}: {}'.format(author, content))
        print('Channel: {}'.format(channel))
        print(' ')
        message.content = message.content.lower().replace(' ', ' ')
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Not actually a dupe because you're not using the `commands` extension.  If you do choose to use that extension (I recommend it) consult [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120312/how-to-make-a-command-case-insensitive-in-discord-py) and the linked github issue.  [If you're on the `rewrite` branch, you can pass `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', case_insensitive=True)` to get case-insensitive commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.case_insensitive).

Comment: How do i use rewrite

Comment: [How to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686388/how-to-install-discord-py-rewrite) and [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/index.html)

Comment: https://gyazo.com/83fd732231227c9cb9796fe76c5fbfe1i can't install

Comment: Ask a new question and post all of the relevant error details in that question as text.  (That link is returning 404)

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2d413799ad9c328e93a9d12c13ca8bef can you just help me here

Comment: Try running `pip install "yarl<1.2"` first.

Comment: same error should i uninstall the old discord.py

Answer (score 0):

Often times you will see programs have a specific character which indicates a command, like and exclamation point or something. I would recommend this. So you make the command for "say" like this.

```
!say Hi
```

Then, when looking at the command, do something like this:

```
input = message.content
if input[0] == '!':
    input = input.split(' ')
    cmd = input[0].lower()[1:]
    params = input[1:]

else:
    cmd = None
    params = input

if cmd == 'say':
    content = ' '.join(params)
```

Something like that, if you have any other questions feel free to ask.

Edit:

So you want to take some input such as 
    ">Say Hello"
And turn it into
    ">say Hello"

Lets approach it like this:

```
content = message.content

if (content[0] == '>'):
    vals = content.split(' ')
    vals[0] = vals[0].lower()
    content = ' '.join(vals)
```

The value you want is stored in the variable "content"

Comment: Huh? Thats odd, you are only making the first word lowercase. Are you sure you are splitting it before you do the .replace(' ', '')?

Comment: i think i know what im doing wrong one second let me test

Comment: the problem is with if cmd == 'say':
            content = params.join(' ')
the bot doesn't know what cmd is

Comment: Ah, I see, I forgot the other case for if there us no !, let me make an edit

Comment: new error `content = params.join(' ') AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'` also sorry if this is annoying you

Comment: My bad, it is ' '.join(params)

Comment: `if input[0] == '>':
IndexError: string index out of range` e.e

Comment: Did you input an empty string?

Comment: no i didn't i said >say Hi also this doesn't convert the command because when i did >Say hi it said `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "Say" is not found` so it doesn't convert the command still

Comment: Im not sure what to say without looking at it closer, but it looks like Patrick, who commented on the question, knows a method using already available code. Id look into that

Comment: Also, as a note, I just ran that code with a few test cases and it worked fine. At this point the issue might be different from the original question, in which case you need to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a white list of commands you don't want to convert to lowercase. Split the message along spaces. Then you can use a nested for loop to check every word against the whitelist. If there is a match, convert the word to lowercase, otherwise keep it the same. Finally merge the list of words back into a sentence.

```
whitelist = 'say', 'play'
text = 'SaY hello'
words = text.split(' ')
for i in range(len(words)):
    for cmd in whitelist:
        if words[i].lower() == cmd:
            words[i] = words[i].lower()
finaltext = ' '.join(words)

print(text)
print(finaltext)
```

The output will be:

```
SaY hello
say hello
```