# How to make discord.py bot case-insensitive?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a python discord bot, and I  don't want the bot to care about the command being in lower/upper case.

How can I do that without `aliases=['clear', 'Clear']`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a command case insensitive in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120312/how-to-make-a-command-case-insensitive-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 3):

Use the lower method. `"Clear".lower()` returns `"clear"`.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's answer will absolutely work when using the `on_message()` event.

However, if you're using command decorators and the `commands` module, you can do the following; when instantiating the bot, you can add the `case_insensitive` kwarg:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=..., case_insensitive=True)
```

---

**References:**

- [`on_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)
- [`commands.Command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command)
- [`commands.Bot()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot)
- [`Bot.case_insensitive`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.case_insensitive)