# I am coding a bot for discord and I would like this if string not to be case sensitive but I can't figure out how

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the line I would like to not be case sensitive:
if message.content.startswith('.rich'):
I am tying to make it lowercase but I haven't figured out how to implement it in the code

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive

client = discord.Client()

from discord.utils import find

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('.rich'):
    embed1 = discord.Embed(title='Richard I (Flag Defense)')
    embed1.set_image(url='https://cdn.rok.guide/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/richard-flag-defense-talent-build.jpg')
    embed1.set_author(name='Talent Builder', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/821829884967649291/860267265404305473/TB7.2t.png')

    embed2 = discord.Embed(title="Richard I (Garrison)")
    embed2.set_image(url='https://cdn.rok.guide/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/richard-i-garrison-talent.jpg')
    embed2.set_author(name='Talent Builder', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/821829884967649291/860267265404305473/TB7.2t.png')

    embed3 = discord.Embed(title="Richard I (Infantry)")
    embed3.set_image(url='https://cdn.rok.guide/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/richard-i-infantry-talent.jpg')
    embed3.set_author(name='Talent Builder', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/821829884967649291/860267265404305473/TB7.2t.png')

    await message.channel.send(embed=embed1)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed2)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed3)```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a command case insensitive in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120312/how-to-make-a-command-case-insensitive-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing this line

```
if message.content.startswith('.rich'):
```

to this:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('.rich'):
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to make your string case sensitive is to use the `.lower()` method like this:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('.rich'):
# '.rich' must be lowercase for anything to return true
```

The `.lower()` sets every character to its lowercase self. This will allow any capital or lowercase letters to pass through the if statement not case sensitive.