# Why is this not working for my Discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm currently working on a Discord bot for a server I moderate (and hope to eventually get onto the dev team for the project we run). It was working just fine when my code looked like this:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

I had an issue with this however, and that is that the command was case sensitive and allowed anything to follow the command. I tried following something I found on another post here and came up with this:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower == "!hello":
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")
```

Now that I do that, the command doesn't work. Is the issue the exclamation point in the string? That's my best guess, but what do I know? If there's a way to do this that makes implementing more commands easier, I'm willing to start the code over because I don't have many commands implemented yet, but I need to add more in the future. If this is a relatively easy way to do it, while doing what I want it to (respond to commands that have an exclamation point at the beginning, the letters in the right order with no extra letters, and not pay attention to case, with a simple message) then simply fixing the issue with this method not functioning would be acceptable.

Comment: `lower` is a method. You want to call it with `lower()`. (When debugging issues like this, try printing the variable(s) in question to see whether their value is what your expect.) Also, take a look at the [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) module for an easier way to implement prefixed commands. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48120312/12975140) about case insensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

`lower` is a method. So if you want to use it, you should use `lower()`. So your code should look like this:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower() == "!hello":
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")
```

Hope this helps:))

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by CrazyChucky, its `lower()` that you want. And the comment regarding commands is probably one that might help you out a bit. If you want to achieve the same thing using a command it would look like this:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
        await ctx.send("Hello!")
```

This way you predefine that all commands starts with `!` and you can set up more commands easily. Instead of the message you have something called context or `ctx` as it's always referred to. `ctx.send` is the same as writing `ctx.channel.send` so you can see the similarity between it and `message` that you previously used.

You mentioned that you didnt want to allow anyone to write anything after the command. And this also achieves that, however, if you at any point *want* someone to follow up on the command with some additional information it is very easy to add this. Simply by adding a second parameter to the function that can later be accessed:

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx, args):
        await ctx.send(args)
```

If a user then calls the command using `!hello world` the bot would send `world` back to the channel.