# How do I make the command work regardless of the case. discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

How do I make the command work regardless of the case? that is , the user can write !Teama, !TeamA, !TEAMa, etc. and the command should work anyway?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZfzB.png

that's my code:

```
a = "asd"
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def teama(ctx):
    await ctx.send(a)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a command case insensitive in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120312/how-to-make-a-command-case-insensitive-in-discord-py)

Comment: Also in the future, it helps the site if you search for your title before posting it, as you can sometimes find answers already on the site. To find the post I linked above, I simply pasted your title into google's search and it gave me that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to specify it when declaring the bot:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)
```